# Access to the path 'c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\config\' is denied

Tags: c#, permission-denied

```
if (Fubrowse.HasFile)
{
  string path = Path.GetFullPath(Fubrowse.PostedFile.FileName);
  //string root = Path.GetPathRoot(path);
  GetFilesFromDirectory(path.Substring(0, path.LastIndexOf("\\")));
}
else
  GeneralClass.ShowMessageBox("Please Select File First.");
}

private void GetFilesFromDirectory(string DirPath)
{
  try
  { 
    DirectoryInfo Dir = new DirectoryInfo(DirPath);
    FileInfo[] FileList = Dir.GetFiles("*.cs", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    foreach (FileInfo FI in FileList)
```

Here, path is `c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\config\`. I want to get all sub directories's file name in `FileList` array.

Comment: So.. to clarify... you want to list the files in a directory.. and this includes files from `c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\config\` folder ?

Comment: Is the problem that you have no permission to access **all** files or **any** file at all? What happens if you only try to list files in *one* directory? Can you read the contents of **any** file what so ever?

Answer (score 0):

The Windows account that's running your code needs read access to the folder (that typically requires admin rights).

- If you're running the program from Visual Studio, that's your account.  Run VS as administrator and your code should work should work.
- If it's a web app, the app pool account needs read access to the folder.
- If it's a windows service, the host account needs access.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I couldn't get files from the `C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\config` because my system was 64 bit and my request got redirected to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\config`

More explanation is given by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23327624/2674033).

Comment: I don't have "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\system32\intesrv\config". My system has a  "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv" directory.  However, that doesn't open either.