# Why can I see file in cmd32 but not in cmd64

Tags: windows, cmd, 32bit-64bit

The file is in C:\Windows\System32, but I can  only see it in git bash, not in CMD.

I've selected ‘Show hidden files, folders and drives' and unchecked ‘Hide protected Operating System files(Recommended)’.

And CMD is opened as Admin.

git bash

```
$ pwd
/c/Windows/System32

$ ls VistaScan.dll
VistaScan.dll
```

CMD (Admin)

```
C:\Windows\system32>dir VistaScan.dll
 Volume in drive C is Acer
 Volume Serial Number is A458-F2EA

 Directory of C:\Windows\system32

File Not Found
```

And my OS is Windows7

**Update:**

Finally , I found the file is in C:\Windows\SysWOW64. It's a 32-bits DLL.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WoW64

So I can see it in C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe

```
C:\Windows\System32>dir VistaScan.dll
 Volume in drive C is Acer
 Volume Serial Number is A458-F2EA

 Directory of C:\Windows\System32

29/01/2011  08:49 AM           629,328 VistaScan.dll
               1 File(s)        629,328 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  789,607,657,472 bytes free
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [File getting copied to SysWOW64 instead of System32](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10100390/file-getting-copied-to-syswow64-instead-of-system32)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps VistaScan.dll has the 'hidden' attribute. In which case, you could do:

```
dir /ah VistaScan.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

The file may have the `hidden` attribute on, in which case you could use this command to reveal it:

```
DIR /AH VistaScan.dll
```

Or it could be `system`, in which case the `/AS` switch would help:

```
DIR /AS VistaScan.dll
```

If it's both, either of the above would work.

Alternatively, you could use `ATTRIB`, which would display the file regardless of whether the file is `hidden` or `system` (or both):

```
ATTRIB VistaScan.dll
```

The output might look something like this:

```
A  SH        C:\Windows\System32\VistaScan.dll
```

The `SH` could be just `S` or just `H`, `S` standing for `system` and `H` for `hidden`.