# Write file to System32 directory

Tags: c#, .net, windows

For curiosity purpose I was trying to copy a COM dll to System32 and the register it. But when copying it I noticed a strange behaviour, this is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        var sysPath = @"C:\Windows\system32\SomeDll.dll";
        File.Copy("SomeDll.dll", sysPath, true);
        var data = File.ReadAllBytes(sysPath);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Error handling
    }
}
```

`File.Copy` runs correctly without throwing errors, but if I check the filesystem I can't find SomeDll.dll in system32. (even trying to open it in an external program by passing the full path fails).

Then, `data = File.ReadAllBytes(sysPath);` runs correctly and data contains the content of the file.

What's happening?
Is there a protection mechanism on .NET that blocks me?

(The application runs with admin privileges)

Comment: Possibly related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10100390/file-getting-copied-to-syswow64-instead-of-system32. Check if your DLL is in sysWOW64 instead

Comment: Are you writing a virus?  "for curiosity purpose" sounds a bit fishy...

Comment: @roryap Why asking? For curiosity purpose?

Comment: One of the major points of COM components being registered is that they *don't* need to be in a specific directory (and certainly not one "owned" by the OS)

Comment: Your codes works without any problem. DLL is there, you can see it using windows explorer.

Comment: @x -- did you test it running on x64 or x32?

Comment: @x... Sorry, I wasn't clear: is your test code project targeting x86 (not x32, my bad) or x64?  That makes a difference.  If you target x86 it will put it in the sysWOW64 folder if I have that correct.

Comment: Target x86 goes to C:\Windows\SysWOW64, target x64 goes to C:\Windows\System32, target AnyCPU goes to C:\Windows\System32