# C# use File.Copy() copy a file into %systemroot%\system32, but the result is that the file was copyed into %systemroot%\SysWOW64?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, windows-7, 64-bit

I have no clue as to executing File.Copy(@"D:\test.txt", "%systemroot%\system32\test.txt"), why the file test.txt was copied into %systemroot%\SysWOW64??

Comment: I did *effort* ! 5 seconds of my time brought me this [surprise](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10100390/file-getting-copied-to-syswow64-instead-of-system32). Google your issue first, there might be a *good* chance that there is already an answer to your issue.

Comment: I first google, but I do not find similar issue! I am sorry ,I could do not see

Answer (score -1):

Because %windir%\system32 is reserved exclusively for 64-bit applications,on 64-bit versions of windows, 32-bit applications that  attempt to access the %windir%\System 32 directory are automatically and transparent redireceted to 32-bit %windir%\syswow64 directory.

The easiest is probably to just compile your utility as a 64-bit application.